# callback mechanism function with ChannelAwareMessageListener

Tags: callback, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I have a queue where listener is listening to a queue with some pre-fetch count lets say 10. It is passing these 10 elements to some processor. 
The processor may process some task or may not or delay it. And i want to dequeue it ( `channel.basicAck(message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), false);` ) from queue after i receive such information.

What could be best way to achieve that ? One idea came to me that i create another queue and i will push processed messages with delivery tag and channel reference into it from processor. And i will listen to this new queue and do ack based on that.

Answer (score -1):

Channels are not thread-safe - see the [rabbitmq documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html).

> Channel instances must not be shared between threads. Applications should prefer using a Channel per thread instead of sharing the same Channel across multiple threads. While some operations on channels are safe to invoke concurrently, some are not and will result in incorrect frame interleaving on the wire. Sharing channels between threads will also interfere with * Publisher Confirms.

You should only use the channel exposed by a `ChannelAwareMessageListener` on the listener thread itself.

If you are trying to achieve concurrency, it's generally better to use the container's `concurrentConsumers` property rather than handing messages off to other threads.